# Roots of a polynomial of degree 5 in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, galois-theory

I have a polynomial $p(u,v) \in F_q[u,v]$ which is symmetric. In case $q \equiv −1\pmod{10}$, by experiment, I understood that $p(u,v)$ is irreducible. But for every $u \in F_q$, $p_u(v)$ is product of a linear and two quadratic polynomials.Now I want to proof this. Can you introduce references that help me?

$p(u,v)=(u^3 + 1/2(-5t + 11)u^2)v^5 + (1/2(t + 1)u^4 + 1/2(3t + 29)u^3 + 1/2(-89t + 197)u^2 + (4t -9)u)v^4 + (u^5 + 1/2(3t + 29)u^4 + 1/2(-t + 151)u^3 + (-186t + 409)u^2 + 1/2(89t - 197)u + 1/2(-5t + 11))v^3 + (1/2(-5t + 11)u^5 + 1/2(-89t + 197)u^4 + (-186t + 409)u^3 + 1/2(t - 151)u^2 + 1/2(3t + 29)u - 1)v^2 + ((4t - 9)u^4 + 1/2(89t - 197)u^3 + 1/2(3t + 29)u^2 + 1/2(-t - 1)u)v + 1/2(-5t + 11)u^3 - u^2,$

where $t$ is $\sqrt 5 $ in $F_q$.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are assuming that $q$ is odd and $5$ is a quadratic residue in $\Bbb{F}_q$, i.e. that $q=p^k$ with either $k$ even or $p\equiv\pm1\pmod{5}$? Also, where did this polynomial come from? And it seems that your polynomial is not of degree $5$, but degree $8$.

Comment: It is not true that $p_u(v)$ is a product of a linear and two quadratic polynomials for all $u\in\Bbb{F}_q$. For example, for $u=0$ and $u=\tfrac{5t-11}{2}$ the polynomial $p_u(v)$ is quartic in $v$.

Comment: The coefficients of the polynomial show a lot of symmetry and structure. Your question would be greatly improved, and an answer would be more likely, if you could explain where this polynomial comes from.

Comment: For example, it is worth noting that
$$-u^5v^5p(-u^{-1},-v^{-1})=p(u,v).$$

Comment: I want to Know the number of  roots of $p_u(v)$ in $\Bbb{F}_q$ in case $q \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10}$ for a fixed $ u \in \Bbb{F}_q$, is there any way to prove the above result, specially using Galois theory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said in my second comment, there is no way to prove the above result because it is false.

Comment: And if you are only interested in $q\equiv\pm1\pmod{10}$ then please include this in your question.